# Prove that $P(X\leq Y)=1$ implies $F_Y \leq F_X$

Tags: real-analysis, probability, measure-theory

Prove that $P(X\leq Y)=1$ implies $F_Y \leq F_X$

I claimed that if there exist $x_0$ $0 \leq F_X(x_0)<F_Y(x_0)\leq 1$ then $P_X(X>x_0)>0$ and $P_Y(Y \leq x_0)>0$ so $P_{X,Y}(X>Y)>P_{X,Y}(X \geqslant x_0 $ and $ Y \leq x_0)>0$ contradiction.

Is there anything I'm missing? I think these two events can be disjoint since there might be the case where $x>x_0$ and $y\leq x_0$ only happens when they are defined on different $\omega$ but the probability each happens individually is positive.

Comment: This is not making any sense. The fact that $P(X>x_0)>0$ and $P(Y\leqslant x_0)>0$ (rather that the mysterious $P_Y(X \leqslant x_0)>0$) is no contradiction and does not imply that $P(X > x_0,Y \leqslant x_0)>0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your argument isn't working. A direct proof is simply
$$F_{Y}(x) = P(Y \leq x) = P(Y \leq x \text{ and } X \leq Y) \leq P(X \leq x) = F_{X}(x).$$

Comment: Can you take a look at my question? Is the situation that I am describing valid?

Comment: I don't think I understand your answer. Why have you introduced subscripts with your $P$?

Comment: Marginal vs Joint

Comment: That's not called for, and anyway, your implications aren't working as @Did has just pointed out.

Comment: @ZHU Indeed there is no marginal distribution here, only $P$ the probability measure on the probability space $X$ an $Y$ are defined on, at every step.